# CakePHP - Empty $this->request->data array after Ajax POST

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to save data which comes from an AJAX POST request in JSON but 
There is empty `$this->request->data` in controller.

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'localhost/pages/register',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: pass_data,

});
```

JSON data:

```
var email = $("#email").val();  
var verifyemail = $("#verifyemail").val();  
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirm_password = $("#vPassword").val();
var pass_data = {
    'data[User][email]':email,
    'data[User][verifyemail]':verifyemail,
    'data[User][password]':password,
    'data[User][confirm_password]':confirm_password,
}
```

I'm use CakePHP 2.3. and jQuery 1.7.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: could you post an example of the `pass_data` you send to the controller?

Comment: if you remove the arrays in the data, is it still the same problem? example `pass_data={'email':email, 'password':password (and etc)}`. The posted data should still show doing `print_r($this->request->data)` on the controller.

Comment: Yes, It is the same - empty array

Comment: check with firebug (or similar) the ajax call and confirm that the data is been transmitted. Also post the action you have for confirming that the action is not receiving data.

Comment: Problem is that $_POST array is empty, why? Firebug says that source is `profile_name=&email=&verifyemail=&password=&confirm_password=&agree=1&time_zone=2`